# Is a right-hand differentiable function differentiable almost everywhere?

Tags: functions, derivatives

Suppose a function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow R$ is right-hand differentiable (right-hand derivative exist on [0,1)), is it true that $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a theorem of Denjoy. It can be found in [Theory of the Integral](https://eudml.org/doc/219302) by Saks (the book is in free access now), Theorem 4.2 on page 270. Here is a direct link to [Chapter IX](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/mon/mon07/mon0709.pdf) with that theorem.

The statement of the aforementioned theorem is more general: it suffices to assume that for every point $x\in [0,1]$ both one-sided limits
$$
\limsup_{h\to 0+} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} 
\quad \text{ and } \quad 
\liminf_{h\to 0+} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}  
$$
are finite (they don't  have to be equal).